# In VS Code extension Azure IoT Tools is not loading AZURE IOT HUB DEVICES

Tags: azure, iot

The instructions say to open the AZURE IOT HUB DEVICES tab in the lower left corner but there is no AZURE IOT HUB DEVICES tab.  There is a AZURE IOT HUB tab but it does not have the menu items the instructions say are there. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Azure IoT Tools installed the extension, the tab for Azure IoT Hub is placed at the bottom of the explorer tab rather than within the Azure Tab on the left pane.

For access: CTRL + Shift + e , then view the bottom left hand corner of the window on the explorer tab.